# Adding gokogiri dependency causes `Killed: 9` exit

Tags: go, gokogiri

The environment I am using is `go1.8` on MacOS Sierra.

The code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"

    "github.com/moovweb/gokogiri"
    "github.com/moovweb/gokogiri/xpath"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("hello world")
    b, _ := ioutil.ReadFile("x.xml")
    fmt.Println(string(b))
    doc, _ := gokogiri.ParseXml(b)
    compiled := xpath.Compile("/path/to/node")
    ss, _ := doc.Root().Search(compiled)
    for _, s := range ss {
        fmt.Println(s.Content())
    }
}
```

After I build and run:

```
$ ./hello-world
Killed: 9
```

Even the `hello world` message is not printed. Later on, on investigating the [gokogiri](https://github.com/moovweb/gokogiri) README, I saw instructions on installing libxml2. So I did `brew install libxml2` and tried, and that also did not fix the issue.

Comment: Probably you also need to install [`libxslt`](http://brewformulas.org/Libxslt). Then after installing both `libxml2` and `libxslt`, I think you need to perform `go get -u github.com/moovweb/gokogiri` to recompile the package.

Comment: Did `brew install libxslt`, still no luck :-(

Comment: I found [this issue](https://github.com/shirou/gopsutil/issues/339). Upgrade to `go1.8.1` or build with `go build -ldflags=-s`.

Comment: @putu your solution works as a charm :-) Can you post that as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [similar issue](https://github.com/shirou/gopsutil/issues/339), and also in [`Golang issue #19734`](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/19734), `cgo` command broken on darwin after performing c tool-chain (Xcode 8.3) update from Apple.

The solution: `upgrade to go1.8.1 or above` or add `-ldflags=-s` to `build` or `test` command, e.g. `go build -ldflags=-s`.